# Display only filenames of files in folder in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

I have a ComboBox in which i want to display the names of files in a certain folder.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Jobs}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

The bound property `Jobs` is of type `List<FileInfo>` which i thought was the most appropriate type to store this kind of information in. A simple `Directory.GetFiles` gets all the files from the given directory in an array which LINQ-Magic transforms into a `List<FileInfo>`.

By default the `ComboBox` now displays the full path to the files. With the `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` parameter i get the `ComboBox` to display only the name of the file and the extension.

What do i have to do to get the `ComboBox` to display only the filename like `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` would give me?

I want to avoid changing `Jobs` to `List<Tuple<string,string>>` or something like that to store the filename and the folder in different variables.

Comment: Either use an `IValueConverter` or change your list items to a custom object with additional properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF it's about visual requirment and you don't want to change your items Source use a [converter](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/) and there you can format your name as you want

Comment: Thank you. Converter was just the thing i was looking for!